# Add space on top of second row of divs in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and have a bunch of boxes in a grid shape (think of a store's items search result page). I want there to be space on top of all the item boxes except for those on the first row. It's hard to do with CSS because they stack differently depending on the viewport size.

I've tried adding a margin top to ALL of them but then I have the space on the top row, too. I would work with that if there was no other option but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

[image]

And here's a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/WL6fET23y2) to work with.

Comment: EDITED TO ADD: I've tried margins. I know I can do it that way but I was hoping to see if there was a cleaner way to do it without unnecessary space at the rows that don't need it.

Comment: Are these boxes always in rows of 3?

Comment: @KevBot it's one big row with a dynamic amount of boxes in each. However there will always be one box per row on mobile, 2 per row in small, 3 per row on medium, and 4 per row for large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less utilized option is to style the nth item, which can take a formula or keywords like odd or even.  So, to skip the first two items and decorate all the rest with a bit of CSS, you could do:

```
.row div {height:50px; background-color:grey; padding:10px; margin:0 10px;}

.row div:nth-child(n + 3) { margin-top: 10px;}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I was looking for. What does the n+3 mean? 3rd one and after? I guess I can do a separate one for each viewport.

Comment: Yes.  So you cold do 3n+0 and it would be every third item.  Here we're starting on the third with n+3.  I mostly use this for making an alternating row color on my table tr tags with nth-child(odd).

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help, this will work out great for me!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do margin-bottom instead?

Comment: I can but that seems a bit hacky to me. I'm aiming for the "right" way if there is one ;)

Comment: The 'right' way would be to separate them in using `row` but that eliminates some responsive functionality.  `margin-bottom:` is probably the most expedient path to your solution.

Comment: @RobertC I would do that but this is a dynamic page and there's no way for me to know how many items will be displaying so I have to do one big row.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22611/)**.

You have to add margin to the right and bottom :

```
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
__________^____^___________ //Right margin
_______________^___________ //Bottom margin
```

Instead of :

```
margin: 0 10px;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't add margin to the right because then my grid has space on the right side for no good reason ;)

Comment: So how you plan to add outside space without using margin ?

Comment: I am using a div within a div. The outer div has padding so the inner div is smaller, leaving space outside each one without margins.

Comment: I can't see that in your OP ?

Comment: Because that was besides the point. I was asking for space on top of all rows minus the first.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this it works http://www.bootply.com/3gxtw6XOnG this way works on mobile as well

```
.row div {height:50px; background-color:grey; padding:10px; margin:0 10px;margin-bottom:10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I can come up with that is 'smart' and won't interfere with the rest of Bootstrap.  Create a new class called `.row-grid` and apply a `margin-bottom` value to the relevant columns like so:

```
.row.row-grid [class*="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You might need to expand that further, to account for additional margins or padding applied by `.row` but it should achieve the look you want without needing to rely on additional wrapper classes within each column.

Answer (score 0):

[**transform**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) the container up by the amount of the margin:

```
.container {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.container > div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #cfc;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```